# Calling predict on an example from an already trained logistic regression model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I trained a logistic regression model for multi classification on text data. I wanted to generate a sample prediction from the model but I am getting this error

```
ValueError: X has 30 features per sample; expecting 100000
```

Here is the code that vectorizes the text data

```
tfidf_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('tfidf' ,TfidfVectorizer(max_features=50000, ngram_range=(1, 3), stop_words = 'english', strip_accents= 'ascii',))])

preprocessor_pipeline = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
    ('short_description', tfidf_pipeline,'short_description'),
    ('details', tfidf_pipeline,'details'),
])
```

Here is the code I am trying to run but getting the latter above error

```
d = {'short_description' : ['[mitigated]  [ubl5] ssd slam station not working'],
    'details' : ['ssd slam station not working, unable to  take slam from the station.']}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
X = df_test[['short_description', 'details']]
X_prep = preprocessor_pipeline.fit_transform(X)
y_p = lr.predict(X_prep)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `preprocessor_pipeline` has to be the same for the training and test step.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

raw_input = [
    "first sentence looks like this",
    "second sentence looks like that",
    "it's going to demonstrate something",
]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words="english", strip_accents="ascii")

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(raw_input)
y = np.array([0, 0, 1])

clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X, y)

d = {
    "short_description": ["[mitigated]  [ubl5] ssd slam station not working"],
    "details": ["ssd slam station not working, unable to  take slam from the station."],
}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
X_test = vectorizer.fit_transform(df_test)
print(clf.predict(X_test))
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vectorizer_test.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(clf.predict(X_test))
  File "/home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py", line 309, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
  File "/home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py", line 289, in decision_function
    % (X.shape[1], n_features))
ValueError: X has 2 features per sample; expecting 6
```

It needs `transform` instead of `fit_transform`:

```py
X_test = vectorizer.transform(df_test)
print(clf.predict(X_test))
# [0 0]
```